# Apache tag used for two different vechicles

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

The tag wiki of [apache](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) tag states that,

> The Chevrolet Apache model is a truck which was released in 1958

However among the two questions in the tag, [one question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/27042/40259) points to the Chevrolet Apache while the [another](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/47881/40259) points to [TVS Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TVS_Apache).

Should we create two tags [chevrolet-apache](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevrolet-apache) and [tvs-apache](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tvs-apache) to replace the [apache](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) tag?

---

**Update**: Chenmunka suggested in comments that [apache](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) to be renamed to [chevrolet-apache](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevrolet-apache) and a new tag is created for [tvs-apache](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tvs-apache).

Comment: It may be simpler to rename the tag for Chevrolet and then create just one more for TVS.

Comment: @Chenmunka I think that is the better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is create a [tvs-apache](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tvs-apache) and left the original one alone. It should be obvious the [tvs-apache](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tvs-apache) is for the motorcycle, though both will appear when someone puts "apache" into the tags. The reason I've done this is, you cannot just "rename" a tag. If I were to create [chevrolet-apache](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevrolet-apache) and moved the the single question there, the old tag would go away as well as any associated wiki data.

If there continues to be an issue, then we'll look at it at that time. If someone would like to update the [tvs-apache](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tvs-apache) wiki with pertinent data, that'd be awesome.

Comment: I'll update tvs-apache wiki. Thank you.